# C++でbool型の引数に(hoge == 0)

Tags: c++

初歩的な質問で恐縮ですが
HOGE classのメンバ変数として

```
const bool abc;
```

が宣言されており
コンストラクタHOGEに

```
abc((hoge1 & hoge2) == 0);
```

が記述されています。

これはbool abcが0で初期化されるだけでしょうか。
それとも全く別の意味を持つのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

式`(hoge1 & hoge2) == 0`の値(`true`または`false`になる)が`abc`の値となります。

つまり`(hoge1 & hoge2)`の値が`0`であれば`abc`の値は`true`に、そうでなければ`false`になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。回答を読んで理解できました。( (hoge1 & hoge2)  == 0)がabcの値になるというのは、コンストラクタの初期化の書き方と照らし合わせると、大変納得できます。